# The articles with specific and less specific objects

Tags: articles

Let's assume I have a lot of everything (motherboards,glasses etc)
From specific to not-specific

The motherboard is broken but NOT A motherboard is broken

A Glass is broken and the glass is broken - Both are correct

A chair is broken and the chair is broken - Both are correct

A tree is broken and the tree is broken - Both are correct

It's all according to my New Zealander teacher.
What makes  a motherboard so special? What if I would talk about a PC?

Comment: Don't think I've heard of a "broken" tree, though,

Comment: If a stem is broken, can I say so in this instance?

Comment: It really depends on context. You could say "A motherboard is broken" in the context of the act of picking up a motherboard and breaking it.

Comment: I was just saying we don't think of trees as "breaking", rather "splitting", "falling down", "toppling" etc.

Answer (score 1):

Using "the" implies you have a specific *something* in mind which you are referring to or which is understood by context.

> **the** motherboard = a specific motherboard in the box

Using **a** implies you are referring to *any one of a collection of *something*

> **a** motherboard = any one of *the* motherboards in the box

"Motherboard" in and of itself is not a special noun, however most people will know there is only *one* motherboard in a computer.

Comment: Will it be a mistake to say:"A motherboard is broken"? If I have a few computers in my house?

Comment: It would be correct to say "A motherboard is broken." You will probably immediately be asked "Which one?"

Comment: Why so my teacher told me that "A motherboard is broken" is not correct even if I have  2 of them?

Comment: Your teacher is probably assuming you are talking about a motherboard in a computer: "the motherboard is broken", "the mouse does not work", "the screen is broken"